# AutoCAD Block comparison from file

Tags: vb.net, block, autocad

I am not asking for the answer, as that seems to upset some people, but does anyone know if the AutoCAD block table keeps a record of the block creation data (such as the date etc) that can be accessed?

My scenario:
I have a drawing of whatever. I insert a block called BlockA.dwg, that was created on monday. BlockA.dwg is then updated on wednesday.

I want to be able to run a command that checks if the block in my drawing is the latest version on file.

Can this be done? Has anyone else ever come across this need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCAD does not store this type of data at the entity level.

You could try adding an xrecord with a date stamp or other data you require.  Please note that this will be attached to the block reference in the file, not the original BlockA.dwg.  You could check the xrecord date stamp and then compare it to the modified date of the original file.

It's not a bulletproof solution but could get you going in the right direction.